# Javascript change CSS page with javascript buttons and save based on cookie

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies, cursor

All right, folks! Here is the basic gist of this question:

I wish to create a cookie on the user's computer called cursor with the value of yes by default. Then, I want to create two buttons on the home page. One of them will say "Change the cursor to default" and the other will say "Change cursor to new."

They would both modify the cursor cookie. If the cookie's value is set to yes, it will load the main CSS page. Otherwise, it will load an alternate CSS page.

Here is what I have attempted that doesn't seem to work:

In the head tags:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {

window.onload = function() {
var curcookie=getCookie("cursor");
if (curcookie===null) {
    curcookie = "";
}
if(curcookie === "no") {
    changecookie();
}
function getCookie(name) {
var nameEQ = name + "=";
var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) != -1) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
}
return null;
}
function changecookie() {
    var oldlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(5);
    var newlink = document.createElement("link");
    newlink.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
    newlink.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
    newlink.setAttribute("href", "http://example.com/alt.css");
    document.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0).replaceChild(newlink, oldlink);
}
</script>
```

In the body tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("cursoroptions").innerHTML = ("<input type=\"button\" value=\"Change the cursor to default\" onclick=\"document.cookie = \"cursor=no\"\"" /><br /><input type=\"button\" value=\"Change the cursor to new\" onclick=\"document.cookie = \"cursor=yes\"\"" />);
</script>
<div id="cursoroptions"></div>
```

Another note is that I am using GoDaddy if that means anything.
I hope this is information is good enough. If not, please tell me so.

Thank you!

**Update:**

Thank you for all of your help, Akshay!
Using what you said and what I knew, here is the final code that worked for me.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].setAttribute("id", "linkcss");
Hellocookie();

function Hellocookie() {
   var curcookie = getCookie("cursor");
   if (curcookie === null) {
      curcookie = "";
   }
   if (curcookie === "no") {
      changecss2();
   }
   else {
      changecss1();
   }
}

function getCookie(cname) {
   var name = cname + "=";
   var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
   for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
      var c = ca[i];
      while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
      if (c.indexOf(name) === 0) return c.substring(name.length,c.length);
   }
   return "";
}

function changecss1() {
   document.getElementById("linkcss").innerHTML += ('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/firstcss.css">');
}

function changecss2() {
   document.getElementById("linkcss").innerHTML += ('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/secondcss.css">');
}
```

As for the buttons:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {document.getElementById("cursoroptions").innerHTML = ("<input type=\"button\" class=\"mysubmitbutton\" value=\"Change the cursor to default\" onclick=\'document.cookie=\"cursor=no\"' /><br /><input type=\"button\" class=\"mysubmitbutton\" value=\"Change the cursor to Lazybott\" onclick=\'document.cookie = \"cursor=yes\"' />");})
</script>
<div id="cursoroptions"></div>
```

Comment: why are using javascript for your buttons? Easier way would be to just use HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your javascript code is badly formatted.

You are not closing your brackets, and you are writing `onload` twice. That's why your code won't work. And your are using double qutoes in place of single quotes here.

```
onclick=\"document.cookie = \"cursor=no\"\""
```

But you should use.

```
onclick=\'document.cookie=\"cursor=no\"'
```

Here's the proper code.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://example.com/main.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {

  var curcookie = getCookie("cursor");
  if (curcookie == null) {
    curcookie = "";
  }
  if (curcookie == "no") {
    changecookie();
  }
};

function getCookie(name) {
  var nameEQ = name + "=";
  var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
  for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
    var c = ca[i];
    while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') c = c.substring(1);
    if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) != -1) return c.substring(nameEQ.length, c.length);
  }

};

function changecookie() {
  var oldlink = document.getElementsByTagName("link").item(0);
  oldlink.href = 'http://example.com/alt.css';

};
</script>
```

For the body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("cursoroptions").innerHTML = ("<input type=\"button\" value=\"Change the cursor to default\" onclick=\'document.cookie=\"cursor=no\"' /><br /><input type=\"button\" value=\"Change the cursor to new\" onclick=\'document.cookie = \"cursor=yes\"' />");
</script>
<div id="cursoroptions"></div>
```

**[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8qzzcLu2/)**

Comment: Thank you so much! This works... for the most part. The part where I determine the css based on the cookie doesn't seem to work, though. (Also, I had to use window.addEventListener("load", function(evt) {}) in order to get the document.getElementById to work. If you need more context, here's the **[website](http://lazybotts.com)**

Comment: you still haven't implemented the changecookie() function...instead of replacing the link tag entirely, just modify the href attribute.

Comment: I have now done that. Unfortunately, it still doesn't seem to work. At least, none of the link's href properties have changed.